# How to AutoLayout the buttons in uiview controller in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I have size of 4 inch and i have added 4 icons in 3 different rows of all equal size 60x60. I can have a proper view in iphone 4s,5,5s but not in iphone 6 and 6 plus. So how can i apply auto layout to it and make the icons look bigger and of same ratio in iphone 6 and 6 plus. Can this be made without any coding?

Like this
[image]

This buttons should change its size in iphone 6 and 6 plus i.e. it should get bigger and proper aligned.
Can it is possible without coding?

Comment: Click on the buttons. There is a square icon at the bottom right of the interface builder. Click on that and add aspect ratio 1:1, so the width = height. Then for making the width be relative to width of the Device, first make some calculations to see how big you want them. Then make add equal width for superview and the button and set the multiplier to whatever percentage you want (e.g .3 for 30%)

Comment: @Gasim Do i need coding to do it or can be done using storyboard?

Comment: yes you can set this up completely in storyboard!

Comment: @AndreSlotta I dont know how to do it can u tell me the way to do it?

Comment: Read the [following](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1). It will give you a good start

Comment: Are you using collection view for that image?

Comment: @Gasim No i am not using collection view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple example:

1. drag a button from the object library to your viewcontroller's view in storyboard
2. ctrl drag from your button to your view (drag to the left or the right) and choose **center vertically in container**
3. ctrl drag from your button to your view (drag to the top or the bottom) and choose **center horizontally in container**
4. ctrl drag FROM the button TO the button (yes, the same button) and choose **aspect ratio**
5. in the size inspector check the button's aspect ratio constraint to have a multiplier of **1:1**
6. ctrl drag from your button to your view (drag to the left or the right) and choose **equal widths**
7. in the size inspector check the button's equal width constraint to have a multiplier of **1:3** (or whatever value you like - 1:3 means that that the button's width is one third of the view's width)

that should be it. good luck! :)

Comment: I want multiple buttons

Comment: i understood that but as soon as you get that one button to work more buttons shouldn't be a problem... :)

Comment: no i m not able to get it for all buttons but on single i can do it.

Comment: where do you want that other buttons to be?

Comment: check the image so that u can understand what i want

Comment: i want this buttons to be having proper space and in center according to the device screen

Comment: Thnx for the demo project i got what i want. But i would like to have a video tutorial if u can upload then it would be great help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76351/discussion-between-parth-adroja-and-andre-slotta).